# Is there a tool can convert simple .xib to Objective-C code automatically?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, nib

Is there a tool can change simple .xib to Objective-C code automatically?
I want to I do GUI design in Interface Builder and use the tool convert the .xib file to Objective-C code.

Is it possible?

Comment: Cool question! (consider changing your name to something unique.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible, but why not just use the xib?

If you *must* do this, though, I'd check out `nib2objc`: https://github.com/akosma/nib2objc